# Create CosmosDB graph in python in Scale

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases

I am trying to import a local graph into the Cosmos DB graph database in python with Gremlin API. I followed the instructions in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-python

A couple of question when I am trying to upload a large database(~15k vertices)

- I can upload 15-20 nodes, however the uploading will stop with more nodes(by stopping I mean the client don't respond anymore and there is no errors too)
- I thought it could due to the throughout for the Cosmos DB, so I have a time.sleep(1) between two queries, but the issue in the first point is still the same
- How can I check the backlog of the Cosmos DB in the portal?
- Why there is no error in client side event if the query is not valid....which is frustrating during debugging phase

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For out-of-box functionality to perform bulk operations in Azure CosmosDB, please try out BulkExecutor library, however the support seems to be limited to .NET and Java for now.

You can download the Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor nuget package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor/).

For reference only, [.NET Sample of Bulk Executor Utility for Azure CosmosDB Gremlin API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-graph-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started).

Hope it helps.